# If I install Ubuntu 14.04 on my PC, what will happen to my files?

Tags: 14.04, files, lts

[image]

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin) on my laptop, and it was not booting properly so I decided to boot from a pen drive, but as I was just installing Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) I thought: What will happen to my older files? I can't run a back up as my Ubuntu 12.04 is corrupted and is not booting. So just before installing, I want to ask, *what will happen to my files*?

I am running Ubuntu as a trial version. I am booting it directly from the drive.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you install 14.04 alongside 12.04 your files will still be on the other partition, and you may be able to access them.  I can access the files on my Windows partition from Ubuntu, but it might be different having 2 Ubuntu operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can perfectly use the live .iso and select the option to upgrade, your personal files will be preserved and you just need to enter your previous credentials (user, password) if you want to use the same home directory, it applies to both unencrypted and encrypted home.

Backups are always good idea.

Answer (score 1):

This applies if your home folder is not encrypted. Boot from the Ubuntu 14.04 live USB/CD and mount your Ubuntu 12.04 partition, You can move them to the other partitions or any backup media you use. After moving all your files from the Ubuntu 12.04 partition (make sure you have no important files left), open [GParted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted) and delete the Ubuntu 12.04 partition and create it as a new partition and install 14.04 in it.

Installed programs can't be recovered.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two partitions on your pen drive. The first partition is for booting the Ubuntu installer and the second partition for storing your files. Or you can prepare one pen drive for booting the Ubuntu installer and prepare one flash drive or your phone memory if it is big enough for your file.

Boot the Ubuntu installer. Don't install it, just try it, and then open the file manager and browse your hard drive and copy all your files you want to keep to your flash drive, phone memory, or anything else you can mount on your PC.

Then unmount your hard drive so you can run the installation and do the full installation so you have one Ubuntu OS, not two. I hope this helps. ;)

Answer (score 0):

- Just decrease the size of `/dev/sda3` ext3 partition through gparted partition editor and create a new ext4 partition from that unallocated space.
- Now run the Ubuntu installer and choose something else option to install Ubuntu 14.04 on the newly created ext4 partition.